# Linked server error OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I'm trying to create linked server from server A (sql server 2008) to server B (sql server 2000). I've done to create the linked server connection, but I've got some error when I run query as shown below,

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "SERVER_A" returned message     "Unspecified error".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "SERVER_A" returned message     "The stored procedure required to complete this operation could not be found on     the server. Please contact your system administrator.".
Msg 7311, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES_INFO" for OLE DB provider      "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "SERVER_A". The provider supports the interface,     but returns a failure code when it is used.
```

Need help.

Comment: First of all please verify that the server_B is added as linked servers, and does have authorization for Server_A in Server_B.

Comment: yes, i already added as linked server, but still doesn't work.

Comment: does the server has distributed transaction enabled!?

Comment: i dont know, i am newbie in sql server, how can make sure it has or not?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post. Not sure the issue is been fixed for you or not. But in this [blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/roman_rehak/archive/2009/05/10/issue-with-64-bit-sql-server-using-sql-2000-linked-server.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage), they recommended to create this sproc in 2000 server master database. I tried and it worked like a treat for me.

```
create procedure sp_tables_info_rowset_64
  @table_name sysname,
  @table_schema     sysname = null,  
  @table_type nvarchar(255) = null
as
   declare @Result int set @Result = 0
   exec @Result = sp_tables_info_rowset @table_name, @table_schema, @table_type
go
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enable the SQLNCLI10 supplier option only level 0 as SQL 2000 does not support schema conception.

You can enable the option by editing the SQLNCLI10 supplier option and then check the related checkbox.

Hope it helps.

Comment: how can i enable the SQLNCLI10 supplier option? i have no idea about it.

Comment: Under your SQL Server node, go to Server objects=>Linked Servers=>Suppliers=>Right click on SQLNCLI10 and select properties.

Comment: on the properties, there are few items, and only Allow inprocess checkbox that already selected. should i select another checkbox? which one?

Comment: Only zero level, do you have it ?

Comment: Level zero only this is the exactly name of the option

Comment: yes i have, i already selected level zero checkbox, and now i've this error message: Msg 7430, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Out-of-process use of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" with SQL Server is not supported.

Comment: Appently you cannot connect SQL Server 2000 using this version of SQLNCLI. So in that case, create an ODBC DSN ON the SQL Server 2008 using SQL Server driver for your SQL Server 2000. Once created, in your linked server creation window select the radio button "Other Sources" and in Data Source field type the DSN name. In the security tab, select the radio button to use the current security context to connect onto the remote server